# Access file on a share(File server)

Tags: java, file, remote-access, fileserver, fileshare

I want to access a file server that is not present in my network, but I have credentials of other domain that can be used to access the file.
How do I gain access to the file in share?
Is it possible to gain access to the file using a java program?
Operating System is Windows. I want to read the contents from .txt and .csv files present in the share and display it on a web page.

Comment: What operating system? What does *access* mean specifically? You're going to need to add more details and a more specific question than *Is it possible?*.

Comment: Operating System is Windows. I want to read the contents from .txt and .csv files present in the share and display it on a web page.

Comment: Hello welcome to SO ! Please try to be specific in your question, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . This helps everybody here.

Can you provide us with more informaiton on how the share path of the other domain looks like ? Also have you considered creating a drive map ?

Comment: \\fileserver\fileshare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used jcifs library to solve this. It works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ftp protocol.
And also can make a map drive from share folder on your system. It's a simple solution.